# Route endpoint not found (404) in server.js when called from another directory (Components)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mern

I have a function in the front end of my project which is trying to fetch from "/save-urls" in the server file. It always returns a 404 "Not Found" error.

The call is being made from a file in Components directory and the endpoint is in server.js which is kept in the 'src' folder

```
};

const saveUrlPair = async (originalUrl, shortenedUrl) => {
  try {
    console.log('inside try block');
    
    const response = await fetch("/save-urls", {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ originalUrl, shortUrl: shortenedUrl }),
    });
    if (response.ok) {
      console.log('URL pair saved to DB');
    } else {
      console.error('Failed to save URL pair to DB');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error while saving URL pair:', error);
  }
};
```

Server.js code

```
app.post('/save-urls', async (req, res) => {
  const { originalUrl, shortUrl} = req.body;
  console.log('1');
  try{
    console.log('2');
    const url = new Url({originalUrl, shortUrl});
    await url.save();
    res.status(201).json({message: 'URLs saved successfully'});

  }catch (error){
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
  }
  console.log('3');
});
```

I am running this project in localhost. The client runs in port 3000 and server runs in port 5000.

Console returns this error message after the 404 not found error

> Failed to save URL pair to DB

Folder structure -

```
src
--components 
----file.js (post request "/save-urls" from here) 
--server.js (trying to fetch from here)
```

Comment: Please copy/paste your code in to the question as text. Images of code are not helpful

Comment: Share code as text not as photo or video file, or some other external link and read:[why you should do that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
It would be helpful to see your code in `server.js` to analyze the problem. You're using the `mode: 'cors'`. Are you sending the necessary cors-headers? (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode#cors )

Comment: @kzi I am very new to javascript and MERN. I've added the code you requested. Thank you for your help

Comment: Is that all of the code in `server.js`? Does any of your `console.log` statements in `server.js` get executed?

Comment: That's the function with the endpoint which is not found. The console log statements here do not get executed.